# How to map a js string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have :

```
const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

I would like to create an array of strings containing

```
[aa,ab,ac .. zz ]
```

I could do it with loops but wanted to try using map.

I tried:

```
const baseStrings = [chars].map(x=>chars[x]).map(y=>y+chars[y]);
console.log(baseStrings);
```

This gives:

```
[NaN]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `[...chars]` instead of `[chars]`? What’s the purpose of `.map(x=>chars[x])`? How about using `console.log` to check the _intermediate_ results instead of the useless final result?

Comment: Is it every combo? like "ba" would be in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `split`

```js
const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const array = chars.split('')
console.log(array)
```

And then `flatMap`

```js
const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const array = chars.split('')

const result = array.flatMap(c1 => array.map(c2 => c1 + c2))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `split` will not get a list of characters, but a list of UTF-16 byte pairs. That’s why `Array.from` or `...` is preferred. See [Do NOT use `.split('')`](/a/38901550/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`spread-operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), get list of characters
- Using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), iterate over this list. In each iteration, using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), return a list of combinations for the current character

```js
const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

const list = [...chars];
const baseStrings = list.flatMap(c1 => list.map(c2 => `${c1}${c2}`));

console.log(baseStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[...string]` instead of String.split:

```js
console.log([...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
  .flatMap((i,_,a)=>a.map(j=>i+j)))
```